# Trying to find neighbors in an 2d numpy array using NetworkX in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, oop, tuples

So i want to ask the user for the coordinates (i.e. (0,0)) and pass them on to find the neighbors. How do I effectively access the tuple to have it passed on to get my result? It wont recognize it as it is a string and with the parenthesis. Some Error Warning with the input specified after the dash:

networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The node ('(', '0') is not in the graph. - (0,0)

networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The node ('0', '0') is not in the graph. - 00

networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The node ('0', ',') is not in the graph. - 0,0

```
def get_neighbors(self, coords):
    return list(nx.grid_2d_graph(*self.get_face_value().shape).neighbors((coords[0], coords[1])))
def __repr__(self):
    x = tuple(input('What coordinates in the array shown above would you like to use? ').strip(','))
    return 'Adjacent values at the coordinates specified of side ' + str(self.get_side_chosen()) + ' are ' + \
           str(self.get_neighbors(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you sterilize your inputs so you only allow numbers and require two different inputs? Asking a human to put in whatever they want is asking for issues.

In any case the trouble is that your format is a string and your needing decimal form.
Wrap your coords with int()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).